# Firefox submit form into new tab?

Tags: firefox, safari, forms, browser-tabs

In Safari, if you command-click (Mac) or Control-click (windows) a form submit button, the form submits to a new tab, just as if you command/control-clicked a link. Is there any way to replicate this behavior in Firefox? I find it very useful if there's a form I want to fill out more than once with very small changes. (I.E. a form with 5 fields, where I want to submit it more than once, changing only one of the fields.)

Comment: You can also read https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17754 for an "interesting" story about this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [SubmitToTab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/483) add-on.

> Allows you to submit a form to a new tab or window. Simply middle-click on a submit button, or hold down the ctrl key before clicking on the button.

Comment: That's awesome, exactly what I need. Thanks!!

Comment: This Firefox extension has been renamed to and rewritten as [TabSubmit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tabsubmit/).

Comment: And yet one more time rewritten, as [TabSubmit Basic](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tabsubmit-basic/)

Answer (score 1):

According to [mozillaZine](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=2167205&p=10693121), the SubmitToTab add-on is "dead". You can find a Firefox 4-compatible rewrite in the [TabSubmit](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/tabsubmit) add-on.